# Implementing the clone method

Tags: c#, collections

I have a class representing some data and a collection class (derives from CollectionBase) for it. When I assign one instance of the collection class to another, it was assigned by reference so I implemented `ICloneable` interface.

```
    public void Add(object item)
    {
        InnerList.Add(item);
    }

    public object Clone()
    {
        MyCollection clone = new MyCollection();

        foreach (MyClass item in this)
        {
            clone.Add(item);
        }

        return clone;
    }
```

Now everything is working fine. But when I go through the elements and add them to the clone instance one by one, why don't they get added by reference? How does the `Add` method add it to the InnerList? Why isn't it added by reference? And what if I add an instance of this collection, let's say to a `List` and change the element in the list? Is the original instance going to be changed?

**Edit:** Here's `MyClass`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

    public string Parent { get; set; }

    public string Child { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        IsEnabled = false;
        Parent = string.Empty;
        Child = string.Empty;
    }

    public MyClass(bool isEnabled, string parent, string child)
    {
        IsEnabled = isEnabled;
        Parent = parent;
        Child = child;
    }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        return (!Parent.Equals(string.Empty) &&
                !Child.Equals(string.Empty));
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!obj.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(this.GetType()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return ((MyClass)obj).Parent.Equals(Parent) ||
               ((MyClass)obj).Child.Equals(Child);
    }

    public bool Equals(MyClass myClass)
    {
        if (myClass == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return myClass.Parent.Equals(Parent) ||
               myClass.Child.Equals(Child);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Parent.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:** What I did was

```
MyClass item = new MyClass(true, "test", "test");
MyCollection collection = new MyCollection();

collection.Add(item);

MyCollection newCollection = new MyCollection();
newCollection = (MyCollection) collection.Clone();

newCollection[0].Parent = "changed";
```

Now after this I expected that collection[0].Parent would be changed to "changed" also, but it still stays the same. Wasn't it added by reference to the clone instance?

Answer (score 1):

If the items in your collection are reference types, they are added by reference. If you add something the the cloned collection, it won't modify the original collection.

Comment: But why is the collection a reference type and the custom class that I've created is not?

Comment: @hattenn - it should be. could you share the code for `MyClass`?

Comment: I have added to the question.

Comment: thx. how have you come to the conclusion that `MyClass` isn't a reference type?

Comment: I'll add it to the question too.

Comment: I have added explaining the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how do you want to implement cloning method. If you want to return shallow copy of the object then you can use `Object.MemberwiseClone` method. If you want to return deep copy then you can use `BinaryFormatter` to serialize and deserialize the object/collection. This will return a new object/collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
    [Serializable]
    class CustomClass
    {
        int _id;
        string _value;

        public CustomClass(int id, string value)
        {
            _id = id;
            _value = value;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    class CustomClassCollection
    {
        private IList<CustomClass> _list = null;

        public CustomClassCollection()
        {
            _list = new List<CustomClass>();
        }

        public void Add(CustomClass a)
        {
            _list.Add(a);
        }
    }



    public static class ObjectCopier
    {
        public static T Clone<T>(this T source)
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
            }

            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (stream)
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Use it like:

```
        CustomClassCollection a = new CustomClassCollection();
        CustomClassCollection b = ObjectCopier.Clone<CustomClassCollection>(a);

        a.Add(new CustomClass(1, "A"));
        a.Add(new CustomClass(2, "B"));
        a.Add(new CustomClass(3, "C"));

        b.Add(new CustomClass(1, "A"));
        b.Add(new CustomClass(2, "B"));
```